# Writing .htaccess file for case sensitive files

Tags: css, .htaccess

I just launched my new website today, and I am having some .htaccess file problems. I thought I solved them all before pushing the site out live, but apparently not.

The site: http://OliverCrow.com/

My .htaccess file currently looks something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html

Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php /errors/404.html

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't really have any idea how any of this works, but I got most of it online, and it seems to work.

The problem I am having is that, for example, if I type in "OliverCrow.com/About" everything works fine, but if I type in "OliverCrow.com/about" or "OliverCrow.com/About/" or "OliverCrow.com/about/" everything goes wrong, and it seems the CSS doesn't load for some reason, and I figure this can probably be fixed using the .htaccess file, although I have no idea how to.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just say this first: I don't think you should use .htaccess to fix this issue. .htaccess is unnecessarily complicated when you already have a, I assume, larger PHP code base running your site.

Now carrying on. Your .htaccess file is complex and bloated. You turn your rewrite engine on twice. I just finished a larger PHP project and the only thing I have in my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will give you $_GET['url'] that you can fiddle with. Then you can use something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['url']) && !empty($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    unset($_GET['url']);
    $v = explode('/', $url);

    $lowerCaseAction = strtolower($v[0]);
}
```

Then $lowerCaseAction will be "about" or something similar. But this all depends on your PHP code. It's a little difficult to give you a more precise solution now.